# Working with HTML 5 and IOS Assets

Tags: ios, html, ios5, assets

I need use Assets functionality from IOS from HTML 5

On Android I use a similar syntax like this

file:///android_asset/

Is there any path or way how to work with assets from HTML 5 like that in iOS?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Do you want to use assets from the  app bundle in HTML displayed by your app or do you want to get assets from a cache after you display external HTML content? (or something else entirely?)

Comment: I need assets from the app bundle in HTML thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the path of an asset to read in directly :

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logo" ofType:@"png"];
```

To use an asset from your bundle in a `UIWebView` (referenced from some HTML) :

```
NSString *html = @"<img src='logo.png' />";
NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]; 
[myWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:bundleURL];
```

Docs for [NSBundle here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UIWebView here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).